# Cypress wait till text appear on page

Tags: cypress, reload, cypress-wait-until

I need to wait till particular text is present in my page , if its not there i need to reload the page and retry [probably need to wait up to 3 mins]. i decided to use waitUntil plugin

```
 cy.waitUntil(
        () =>
    cy.get("tr").find("td").contains("mysampletext").reload(true),
        {
          verbose: true,
          errorMsg: "Campaign status failing to synchronize with clickhouse",
          timeout: 180000,
          interval: 30000,
        }
    );
```

Problem for me is , the contains method fails and exit with out reloading. Any other input to address this issue..? i wont be able to use any element as it is very dynamic

I have tried use different recursive method instead of waituntill and it was not success

Comment: Waiting up to 3 minutes seem like an inefficient way to write a test. What determines if the text you're looking for appears? Is there any way to be sure that it appears the first time you load the screen? Is the text coming from an API call?

Comment: Three minutes is the max time. But i am planning to look for text every 30 seconds so if it comes before that. i will proceed further. if not i will fail the TC.
but the real issue for me is how can i able to make sure contains method wont exit

Comment: Is there anyway to _force_ the text to appear sooner? Testing the backend via the frontend is usually considered an inefficient testing method, and I'd recommend only doing it when there are no other options.

Comment: No ,this is not merely a text.  it is basically a status . And status change happens after certain backend process completed. 3 min is the max SLA for that service.
Any way to solve this issue from cypress..?

Comment: You can intercept the backend response and either mock it, or wait until it completes successfully - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept

Answer (score 4):

I'm not convinced `cy.waitUntil()` adds a lot of value to modern Cypress (it was written a while ago).

But one thing Cypress does lack is performing an action like `cy.reload()` during timeout retries.

A recursive function should work for this problem

```js
function waitUntilWithReload(selector, expectedText, interval, error, iteration = 0) {

  if (iteration > 100) {   // set an upper limit to stop infinite retry
    throw new Error(error)
  }

  const text = Cypress.$(selector).text();
  if (text.includes(expectedText) {
    return
  }

  cy.wait(interval)
  cy.reload().then(() => {
    waitForText(selector, expectedText, interval, iteration + 1) 
  }
}

waitUntilWithReload('tr td', 'mysampletext', 30_000, 'Campaign status failing')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution . Problem i am facing this approach is with selector.
"tr td" wont fetch the text for me as it have multiple elements with same locator. thats one of the reason i was using contains in the first place.

Comment: I tweaked a bit in ur code , but problem for me is return from the function
'''
   cy.get("tr").find("td").then(($value) => {
              getText = $value.text()
        
             if (getText.includes(expectedText)) {
                return
             }
        
'''
problem for me is , it is not returning from the function , it returning from the promise and continue in the loop

Comment: On first question - change `tr td` to `tr td:contains(mysampletext)` - it will give you one element.

Comment: On second question - don't do that tweak, it's not correct.